# javafx error when event invokes

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm newbie in javafx, just getting started and ran into bunch of error when an event is called on button. I'm using SceneBuilder 2.0 in NetBeans 8.1 with jdk1.8.
I've created basic layout in scene builder

I created a simple method in my controller class which just gets the text from textField and sets it into textArea. I set it on a button.
Program runs and build just fine but when i click on the button i get errors.

Here's my code:

```
package javafxapp;
import java.net.URL;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TextField chatText;
@FXML
private TextArea chatArea;
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

public void sendMsg(ActionEvent action)
{
chatArea.setText(chatText.getText());
chatText.setText("");
}
```

}

here's my main class:

```
package javafxapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

now here's the error:

```html
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
 at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
 at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1147985808.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
 ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javafxapp.FXMLDocumentController.sendMsg(FXMLDocumentController.java:40)
 ... 73 more
```

I dont know what causing the error, however that 'handleButtonAction' method is working fine.
"apologize if my presentation of question is wrong, I've never asked anything here before"

Comment: can you post your FXML document. Check if your chatText and chatArea are correctly connected to the FXML.

Comment: Yes the error was in connecting the elements, after posting it i checked the code again and saw that the "fx:id" was blank in scene builder. I did not check it before because it is supposed to be connected automatically,so i filled it manually.Maybe it was a software problem. thanks for the quick reply anyways :)

Comment: Great. I added the answer so probably someone else with the same problem can see it.

Comment: Also that I'm facing problem while connecting code from scene builder to IDE. like I've just changed my method from 'handleButtonAction' to 'sendMsg' but its still stuck at first one, I've changed it from scene builder and IDE both, I saved it and clean n built it but still the same. i had to close both program and run it again. should i changed my IDE?

Comment: I dont know what Scenebuilder does if you save your changes there because I dont use it. But I dont think Netbeans should have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements are probably not correctly connected to the FXML. Check if chatArea and chatText are set as fx:id in your FXML.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So there are two **different** ways that I know of to resolve this problem.

Technique 1) To do it the *way* you're already doing it, try this:

```
@FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{//etc...}
```

Technique 2) You can also create a normal method, and then CALL IT from within scene builder, as follows:

```
public void handleButtonAction()
{
      //your code goes here
}
```

Now, go into scene builder, click on the button, navigate to the "code" section of the side panel, and look for "On Action". Inside "On Action", enter the name of your method WITHOUT PARENTHESIS. So, in this case, you would simply type "handleButtonAction". Save the document.

It should work now.

The second one is the technique I recommend in this case. It's just cleaner and better looking.

Let me know if this helped:)